# How to run a join query in sql?

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query on the following:

Users table has id and is_paying.
Subscriptions table has id, user_id, and subscription_plan

I want to get the list of user id's of users that have subscription_plan = 81 and is_paying = 'Y'. When I run

```
select count(distinct users.email) 
from users,subscriptions 
where subscription_plan_id=81 
and users.is_paying_customer = 'Y';
```

The query runs for too long because I don't think it's joining the 2 tables together and I'm unsure how to do this. Any advice?

Comment: There is no join in this query and you will get a single value not a list the way you have it. You are going to need to study up on sql.

Comment: Joining tables is explained in every good SQL tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join a table correctly... you need to find something commen between them. The basic syntax is

```
SELECT fields from Table1 aliasname 
JOIN Table2 aliasname ON
table1aliasname.commonfield = table2aliasname.commonfield
WHERE wherecriteria
```

In this case:

```
select count(distinct users.email) 
from users,subscriptions 
where subscription_plan_id=81 
and users.is_paying_customer = 'Y';
```

What ties users to descriptions.. I will assume you have a field called userID
try something like this:

```
select count(distinct users.email) 
from users u
JOIN subscriptions s on u.userid = s.userid
where subscription_plan_id=81 
and users.is_paying_customer = 'Y';
```

Comment: good point by @trogdor... if you want fields you wouldnt just select DISTINCT count. Whats happening is there probably isnt a common way to join these 2 tables that SQL can figure out and its trying to give you a very large combination... then you throw in a DISTINCT and its trying to look for non-repeats, then you are asking for a COUNT of all those.

Comment: glad to help... when I started SQL I hated joins and were very confused. When I finally figured it out, this is the best way I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of users remove the `COUNT`. Also, you need to put a JOIN condition to combine users with subscriptions:

```
select DISTINCT users.email 
from users JOIN subscriptions ON users.id = subscriptions.user_id
where subscription_plan_id=81 
   and users.is_paying_customer = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT users.id
    FROM users INNER JOIN Subscriptions ON users.id = Subscriptions.user_id
    WHERE (Subscriptions.subscription_plan_id = 81) AND (users.is_paying_customer = 'Y')
) AS DistinctUsers
```